Disconnections with WIFI on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I use a MacbookAir from 2012. Nice hardware but not supported by Apple anymore.
I installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS an was happy for a couple of months.
Now I upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS and everything seemed tp be o.k. at the beginning.
But from time to time the WIFI is disconnected in the middle of the work.
It doesn't seem to be a hardware issue as the same hardware is used in dual boot mode with Ubuntu 22.04/24.04.
Cheers, Johannes
